# Nvelocity String To Double Conversation

Tags: c#, asp.net, velocity, nvelocity

Hi All I'm Using Nvelocity Library and i have some problem so
i Have number 57,45 and i cant convert it to double $Convert.ToDouble($Value) returns 0.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps because it's got a `,` for the decimal mark instead of `.` and the locale is set wrongly for that?

Comment: i also tried that one. i used this method 
.replace(",", ".")

Answer (score 0):

My Code Looks Like this

```
#foreach($gridRow in $gridData)
 #set($tmpPrice = $gridRow.get_Item("Price").replace(",", "."))
 #set($sumPrice = $sumPrice + $convert.toDouble($tmpPrice))
#end
```